# IE8 border using pseudo :after

Tags: html, css

Alright IE8 gurus (does such a thing exist?). I need some assistance in fixing an issue that is a result of using an `:after` pseudo selector. It's pretty straight forward - just trying to add a border (underline) after a `span` tag on hover. No, the easy solution isn't just using the text-decoration property because the element inside the `span` tag is an image (and some other reasons).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="cta">
    Hover over me
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.cta { position:relative; z-index:1; display:inline-block; }
.cta:after { position:absolute; z-index:1; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; content:''; border-bottom:1px solid transparent; }
.cta:hover:after { border-color:rgba(0,136,204,.6); }
```

And for those of you really interested in helping and want to play around with it, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6E6L6/).

Why on earth does that not work on IE8? Works on all other browsers. I've even tried just removing all of the hover nonsense, but I still can't get the border to appear. I've also tried adding a `display:block` and `width:100%` to the `.cta` div per some things I came across on the Internet. No dice.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Why on earth does that not work on IE8?"  Asked and answered in your question, ha ha.  Have you tried rendering it using a hex value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 and lower do not support `rgba`, so try adding a fallback using `rgb`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6E6L6/3/)**

```
.cta:hover:after
{
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(0,136,204);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,136,204,.6);
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: @Adrift, I'm not saying to remove the `:hover`, but to add an additional style to remove the transparency.

Comment: @Adrift: You're right, I didn't even notice that. Thanks for catching it. Changed my answer - would transparent not be overridden by the border-color on hover?

Comment: So this does fix my what's in the fiddle (and above), but doesn't fix the actual issue I'm working with. Must be yet ANOTHER thing in addition to the `rgba` property. Anyhow, thank you!! IE8 just needs to go...

Comment: Agreed. You could try using the IE fallback in the css-tricks link from above.